# Is it acceptable to remove freshly (1 day old) installed porcelain tile and reuse it to correct a bad layout?

Tags: tile, thinset, layout, reuse

With one day of installation work completed I checked the layout and realized it would result in sliver cuts along some of the main walls.  This morning I stopped them from continuing work and their supervisor agreed to have them redo the installation.  They are removing the tile cleaning off the thin set and plan to reuse as much as possible.  The 12x24" tile is not grouted.  Is it acceptable to reuse the porcelain tile after its been installed?  Will there be unseen defects in the tile?

Comment: If not broken and is cleaned it should be as new.  Removing it without breaking it is the problem.  Porcelain is usually good or broken, not much in between.

Comment: Always found the centre lines and worked out… cutting to edges is a fact of life - unless you build the walls around the finished floor.

Answer (score 2):

Generally the thinset has not developed full bond strength by that point, *(take note, folks that like to walk on freshly tiled floors before they are done...)* so reasonable to get it up off the floor intact, and if so, no issue with reusing it if the old thinset is cleaned off.